# PHP get random colors which should compatible with text color white?

Tags: php, background-color

So far this is what I have tried but sometimes it gives very light color .

```
public static function randomColor($minVal = 0, $maxVal = 255)
    {

        // Make sure the parameters will result in valid colours
        $minVal = $minVal < 0 || $minVal > 255 ? 0 : $minVal;
        $maxVal = $maxVal < 0 || $maxVal > 255 ? 255 : $maxVal;

        // Generate 3 values
        $r = mt_rand($minVal, $maxVal);
        $g = mt_rand($minVal, $maxVal);
        $b = mt_rand($minVal, $maxVal);

        // Return a hex colour ID string
        return sprintf('#%02X%02X%02X', $r, $g, $b);
    }
```

Comment: To make the colours lighter, use a max value which is lower than 255, difficult to know what exactly, but 128 should work.

Comment: Btw, a rgb hex string is just a number from 0x0 through 0xFFFFFF, simply generate number in that range ``return '#' . str_pad(dechex(mt_rand(0, 0xFFFFFF)), 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)``

Comment: @FaristaLatuconsina This actually worked .I will put it in the loop and see result if it breaks in any case .

Comment: Or you might want a less complex or simpler code ``return sprintf('#%06X', mt_rand(0, 0xFFFFFF))``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to generate random dark colors. You can also change the darkness threshold by changing `127` in the function parameter.

```
function random_color_part($threshold = 127)
{
    $dt = '';
    for ($o = 1; $o <= 3; $o++) {
        $dt .= str_pad(dechex(mt_rand(0, $threshold)), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
    return '#' . $dt;
}
```

Comment: This is giving very dark colors and if i change max in top of my function so these two behaves same . Thanks mate